# How to set X-Frame-Options header to Jboss-as-7.1.1.Final? The requirement is to set this header in server's welcome page

Tags: server, header, jboss7.x, x-frame-options

The X-Frame-Option is not set in this URL http://portalappdev03:8088/index.html.
The URL renders a Jboss welcome page.

Answer (score -1):

You have to make some changes in two locations of your undertow subsystem:

1. In the `<filters>` section, add the apropriate response header
2. In the `<host>` section, add the corresponding filter reference

Restart JBoss and you are ready to go!